# Is findViewById still needed

Tags: android

Recently after getting back into Android development, as I was reviewing some code, I noticed that code would reference a control directly by its id without the need to use `findViewById`. So if I had a `textview` with an id of `tvUsername`, I could just call:

```
tvUsername.setText("john");
```

In the past I was always using `findViewById` but am now wondering whether the ability to use a control directly without calling `findViewById` always existed, or did Google start supporting directly referencing it after some version.

Comment: *`Is findViewById still needed`* if you are using **`JAVA`** than it is needed, But if you use **`databinding`** than no need to do `findViewById` also in **`KOTLIN`** the `findViewById` is no needed

Comment: one possibility is by using View Binding library like ButterKnife or DataBinding.

Comment: I started using Kotlin, so you are probably right about this being a Java issue. I find that strange though because there is nothing in the Kotlin language that I know of that implicitly allows you to reference a control defined in a layout file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is findViewById still needed

*`Is findViewById still needed`* if you are using **`JAVA`** than it is needed,

But if you use [**`Data Binding Library`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) then no need to do `findViewById`

Also in **`KOTLIN`** the `findViewById` is not needed

You can directly use it like this

```
tvUsername.text ="john"
```

for more information read

- [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)
- [Goodbye `findViewById`, say hello to Synthetic Binding](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/goodbye-findviewbyid-say-hello-to-synthetic-binding-in-kotlin-d3727bd8438e)

Comment: You're right. This appears to be a feature that Kotlin supports for Android (although the language itself does not support that). I'm not using databinding.

Comment: @AndroidDev in kotlin it is possible because of `Kotlin Android Extensions`